# Use of libraries that breach licenses you don't know about

Tags: licensing

Building a commercial product may use various open source libraries that have use of other libraries. In an ideal world you would know which licenses they use and whether it is safe to use them.

However, if you use an open source product (or commercial can apply here also) that is in breach of licensing and you don't know about it how does this affect what you do?

So for example I use Product A that uses a licence than means product A and anything that uses it has to be open source. However Product A has breached the rules but hidden the fact.

Now this means my product is also supposed to be open source but I have no idea it should be. Can i be in breach of the license even though I don't know I am?

Comment: Also depends on where you are. If we are talking US law (ianal and ianaAm) in practice your obligations will be fulfilled if you have made "reasonable" effort to check for infringements. What's "reasonable" can depend on a lot of factors - what's "reasonable" for Microsoft or IBM may well be practically impossible for a garage shop, for example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens I am customizing a EULA for a commercial software component (using a template from a Legal firm) and I found this clause in it

> (b)   that the use of the Software by the Licensee in accordance with the terms of this EULA will not infringe the Intellectual Property Rights of any third party;

What I would do is scour the license of the component you are using as you may find this clause. If so *(Im not a lawyer and this does not constitute legal advise)*, you may be able to reasonably assume that so long as you are complying with the license of the component you do own, you will not infringe the license of any component you do not own.

Comment: I read it that way: The user is using the sofware. So the user may not use the software to infringe *third-party* copyrights. If the software itself already violates this (e.g. using the software is violating third party rights), this paragraph (if not even more, like the whole document) might likely become void.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer (tm), but I'd say that you are responsible, of course. If you use a product A that uses another product B, you must know about that fact that B is used and also you must know about the licensing terms of B, as - effectively - you're using B yourself.

But that's just what I'd expect...

Comment: It's a hypothetical situation, was just curious how it works but I guess this is where the high-paid legal people in my company need to go through these things. Or I avoid sing other libraries of course

Comment: Also, if A is using B then A implictly cannot have a more liberal licence than B, else A is in breach of B's license. Hence, if your app uses A directly  A uses B internally then so long as you use A within license you should be ok. I'm definitely not a lawyer (TM)

Comment: Well, the situation Firedragon described explicitly said "What if A breaches B's license?". So: while you're right that this *shouldn't* happen, the question "What if it happens" is valid. However, I'm not sure whether saying "I was relying on A to conform to B's license agreement" would stand a case...

Answer (score 1):

Licensing is like a chain. If for example one component makes use of some other work in an unlicensed way, the whole chain is broken, the other work can not be rightfully licensed to others.

For copyright it does normally not depend whether you know what you're doing or not. Sounds harsh, just saying upfront as you asked for commercial distribution.

If you create a work, you should do what that requires:

- Locate all third party code you make use of.
- Locate all binary blobs.
- Catalog the components.
- Find out who hold copyright and under which license each compontent is available, retrieve the licenses and store them with the software (if the software does not ship with the actual license text, document from where and why you've stored the texts).
- If it's not clear under which license a component is available, contact the coypright owner/author. You should prefer written communication.
- Verify that you full-fill the requirements of each license.
- Verify that all components are license-wise compatible with each other.

I think doing this pro-actively is important because otherwise you can't argue that you did not know if you can't document what you did know. It would be just meaning that you didn't want to know which hardly can't offer any sort of protection. To which level you need to find out about an identifiable component I would say it depends (saying: How far you need to take this).

Ask your lawyer and do some risk analysis: You might not be legally obligated to check that subcomponent A which makes use of A-B and A-C has properly checked for the right of these two components. But in case it turns out that A-B was violated and A is not rightfully licensed to  you regardless what the licensor of A told you, you can still loose any usage rights for A-B which could turn out that you must drop A. So for critical components you might want to do more than the law requires you to do.

In a commercial context "assuming" might be counter-productive. Ask your lawyer about that.

The work to clarify copyrights and licenses, it's progress as well as the underlying processes should be documented. You should also look for legal help with such processes as if you run into conflicts (and software licensing can be complicated) you need to legally discuss what you have as well. Depending on which components you use, expect this to be quite some work.